# CASE Statement not adding correctly

Tags: mysql

So I have been working on upping my MYSQL and SQL skills, and so to do some I'm building a swiss-system tournament software program. Currently I am looking at calculating a players game win total for tie breaker calculation later on. I'm doing most of the bulk work in MYSQL because it is easier to control all the data management that way.

Here is the table and functions

**Result Set for #round_match**

```
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----+------+------+---------+
| id | round__id | player__id | opponent__id | win | loss | draw | outcome |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----+------+------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |          1 |            8 |   2 |    0 |    0 |       1 |
|  5 |         2 |          2 |            1 |   1 |    1 |    1 |       2 |
+----+-----------+------------+--------------+-----+------+------+---------+
```

**result set for #round**

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | event__id | number |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 |         1 |      1 |
|  2 |         1 |      2 |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

Now the query I'm working on that will manipulate this data to give me a game win percentage

**query**

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN rm.player__id = 1 THEN (rm.win*3)+rm.draw
        WHEN rm.opponent__id = 1 THEN (rm.loss*3)+rm.draw
    END
    ) as game_wins
FROM tournament.round_match rm
INNER JOIN tournament.round r ON rm.round__id = r.id AND r.event__id = 1
WHERE rm.player__id = 1
```

So just a quick overview of what I'm trying to accomplish. Each win is worth three points, a draw is 1 and a loss is 0. I would like to add them all up. I had it set to where player__id for each row was 1 and it gave me the correct result of 10, but when I switch the player__id and opponent__id in the last row it failed and only gave me the count of 6. So it didn't even calculate the last row.

I'm still a bit of a scrub when it comes to MYSQL so any help will be nice on this, I'm really working on getting my skill level up. If you need any clarification or more information please ask! Thank you for all help ahead of time!

Comment: Please share the contents of table `tournament.round`; it will affect which matches are taken into account, due to the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: added the tournament.round results

Comment: Are you just switching the ID in the last row, or are you changing the hard-coded values in the case statement as well?

Comment: i just switch the id in the last row only the case statement has not changed

Comment: So, you're only crunching the scores for the user with ID 1, regardless of which player or opponent you're specifying in the where statement? Is that really what you're trying to do?

Comment: As pointed out by @MHardwick, if that is your issue, replace the last line with `GROUP BY rm.player__id` an that should do the trick..!!

Comment: @MHardwick that worked, if you submit as an answer I will accept and give you points

Comment: @SarathChandra gave the actual answer, I'll let that person go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the last line of the code `WHERE rm.player__id = 1`. This is selecting only one record instead of all the records. Hence, changing the query to

```
SELECT SUM(
CASE
    WHEN rm.player__id = 1 THEN (rm.win*3)+rm.draw
    WHEN rm.opponent__id = 1 THEN (rm.loss*3)+rm.draw
END
) as game_wins
FROM tournament.round_match rm
INNER JOIN tournament.round r ON.rm.round__id = r.id AND r.event__id = 1
GROUP BY rm.player__id ;
```

will return the records for each player.